# Passing ViewModel from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Ok, here is my problem.  I am trying to pass a view model of mine, which has multiple list in it, to my view.  Then in my view i need to edit the different list.  Then on my post i need to save the edits.  Although, when i pass my viewmodel back to my post, it is empty! Can somebody explain what i am doing wrong?

Controller

```
    public ActionResult ManageNewsArticles()
    {
        NewsViewModel newsViewModel = new NewsViewModel();

        newsViewModel.ListBreakingNews = db.NewsArticles.Where(n => n.PageSetupID == 1).ToList<NewsArticle>();
        newsViewModel.ListMainArticle = db.NewsArticles.Where(n => n.PageSetupID == 2).ToList<NewsArticle>();
        newsViewModel.ListSubNews1 = db.NewsArticles.Where(n => n.PageSetupID == 3).ToList<NewsArticle>();
        newsViewModel.ListSubNews2 = db.NewsArticles.Where(n => n.PageSetupID == 4).ToList<NewsArticle>();
        newsViewModel.ListSubNews3 = db.NewsArticles.Where(n => n.PageSetupID == 5).ToList<NewsArticle>();

        return View(newsViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ManageNewsArticles(NewsViewModel newsViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Admin");
        }

        return View(newsViewModel);
    }
```

here is my View

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TrueNews.ViewModels.NewsViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Manage News Articles
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Manage News Articles</h2>

    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm(Model)) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <%: Html.EditorForModel(Model) %>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to Admin Controls", "Admin") %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

NewsViewModel

```
public class NewsViewModel
    {
        public List<NewsArticle> ListBreakingNews { get; set; }
        public List<NewsArticle> ListMainArticle { get; set; }
        public List<NewsArticle> ListSubNews1 { get; set; }
        public List<NewsArticle> ListSubNews2 { get; set; }
        public List<NewsArticle> ListSubNews3 { get; set; }
    } // End of Class
```

Comment: We need the code for the viewmodel too

Comment: just added the view model, nothing special

Comment: Try initializing the lists in the view model constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume that you use linq2sql or something similar.

In order to update an object in your database, that object has to be fetched through a DataContext.

Inside your method "ManageNewsArticles" you're calling `db.SaveChanges();` but since there is no objects loaded through db no rows will get updated.

A solution to this is to fetch all news you want to update, and then use the `Controller.UpdateModel` method to update your actual instances, and then call `db.SaveChanges();` to persist your changes.

Comment: I'm using the entity framework.  And honestly i really didn't finish that part of the save process.  I kinda just put that there for refrence.  I didn't want to finish that until i was getting data back from my view.  And with the Entity framework wouldn't that data still be loaded within the db object?

Comment: Ah sorry, must be tired :) Please post your ViewModel definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the

```
UpdateModel(NewsViewModel);  
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Admin");
```

Comment: It should not be necessary since the view model is an action method parameter. But it might show you the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried using `EditorFor` on lists of complex objects. I'm guessing that MVC is unable to encode your `NewsArticle` objects in such a way that they can be reassembled into a `NewsViewModel` object. Have you tried using something like Firebug to see what the actual `POST` looks like? What are the query parameter keys and values?

You may be able to simply take an `IEnumerable<NewsArticle>`, and then re-parse that out using the same logic you use in the ManageNewsArticles method. Give that a shot, and let us know what you find out.